# Dec sep align & \multicolumn incompatibility?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, pgfplotstable

*As I did not get any answer, I decided to split the two question so that they appear less daunting.
The initial question I am referring to is [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73743/dec-sep-align-string-type-cell-incompatibility)*

Here is a table with *regular* alignment mixed with `dec sep align`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

  \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
  col sep=&, header=false,
  every head row/.style={before row={\toprule%
\multicolumn{1}{l}{a}  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{b} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{c} &  \multicolumn{2}{l}{ddd ddd ddd}\\
% \multicolumn{2}{l}{Glonk}\\
                                    }, after row={\midrule}
                         },
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  display columns/0/.style={column name={Grandeur}, string type, column type={l}},
  display columns/1/.style={column name={Unite}, string type, column type={l}},
  display columns/2/.style={column name={Reference}, dec sep align={l}},
  display columns/3/.style={column name={Reference}, dec sep align={l}},
  display columns/4/.style={column name={Reference}, dec sep align={l}},
                       ]
  {%
glonk  &     z           &  323.1 & 323.1  & 323.1
plokt  &     y           &  33.12 & 33.12  & 33.12
jlorp  &     x           &  3.123 & 3.123  & 3.123
  }

\end{document}
```

And here is what it produces:
[image: buggy-table 2]

Somehow the width of the columns are incorrectly accounted for when
using `dec sep align`.
How could I correct this strange behaviour.

Comment: Please edit your question to make the code fragment a complete document that can be run locally and shows all packages used.

Comment: You are right.
replacing the multicolumn line by

`\multicolumn{1}{l}{a}  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{b} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{c} &  \multicolumn{4}{l}{ddd ddd ddd}\\ `

solved the problem.

Maybe you can put this into an answer that I will be glad to accept?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks from your image as if decimal alignment is implemented using two table columns internally in which case `\multicolumn{1}{l}{c}` should be `\multicolumn{2}{l}{c}`