# Multiple multicolums table making the first row of data disappear. Also need tips on making it better looking

Tags: pgfplotstable

Following this question:

[Multiple Multi columns with pgfplotstable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84907/multiple-multi-columns-with-pgfplotstable)

The first row of my data gets messed up somehow, here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[paperwidth=35cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent\pgfplotstabletypeset[
 every head row/.style={
 before row={\toprule
   &
       &\multicolumn{2}{c}{32-2}
   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{128-4}
   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{256-8}
   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{32-4 w/o LS}
   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{128-4 w/o LS}
   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{256-8 w/o LS}
    },
},
display columns/1/.style={column name={Instance}},
display columns/2/.style={column name={n}},
display columns/3/.style={column name={Avg. Time}},
display columns/4/.style={column name={Avg. Qual.}},
display columns/5/.style={column name={Avg. Time}},
display columns/6/.style={column name={Avg. Qual.}},
display columns/7/.style={column name={Avg. Time}},
display columns/8/.style={column name={Avg. Qual.}},
display columns/9/.style={column name={Avg. Time}},
display columns/10/.style={column name={Avg. Qual.}},
display columns/11/.style={column name={Avg. Time}},
display columns/12/.style={column name={Avg. Qual.}},
display columns/13/.style={column name={Avg. Time}},
display columns/14/.style={column name={Avg. Qual.}},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
string type
]
{
bur26a 26 94.6513 0.9995 145.6622 0.9999 202.7375 1.0000 1.4381 0.9707 2.0208 0.9770 2.9439 0.9786
chr25a 25 84.5684 0.8296 131.5305 0.8881 183.0491 0.9012 1.4192 0.3110 1.9670 0.3369 2.8968 0.3530
}

\end{document}
```

The bunch of &'s near the multicolumns is a hack i found to properly align them to their respective pair of columns.

Those columns style lines are there to make columns have the same name.

Output is this:

[image: Table Output]

Note how the first row isn't there, and there is a bur26a where it shouldn't.

Help?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the first row of your data table contains non-numeric entries, PGFPlotstable assumes that it contains the column names. To switch this off, set `header=false`.

The `columns` numbering starts with `0`, not `1`, which explains your offset.

If you introduce a row above your header row using `before row`, you'll need to terminate that row using `\\`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[paperwidth=35cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent\pgfplotstabletypeset[
 every head row/.style={
 before row={\toprule
   &
   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{32-2}
   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{128-4}
   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{256-8}
   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{32-4 w/o LS}
   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{128-4 w/o LS}
   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{256-8 w/o LS}\\
  },
 after row=\midrule
},
display columns/0/.style={column name={Instance}},
display columns/1/.style={column name={n}},
display columns/2/.style={column name={Avg. Time}},
display columns/3/.style={column name={Avg. Qual.}},
display columns/4/.style={column name={Avg. Time}},
display columns/5/.style={column name={Avg. Qual.}},
display columns/6/.style={column name={Avg. Time}},
display columns/7/.style={column name={Avg. Qual.}},
display columns/8/.style={column name={Avg. Time}},
display columns/9/.style={column name={Avg. Qual.}},
display columns/10/.style={column name={Avg. Time}},
display columns/11/.style={column name={Avg. Qual.}},
display columns/12/.style={column name={Avg. Time}},
display columns/13/.style={column name={Avg. Qual.}},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
string type,
header=false
]
{
bur26a 26 94.6513 0.9995 145.6622 0.9999 202.7375 1.0000 1.4381 0.9707 2.0208 0.9770 2.9439 0.9786
chr25a 25 84.5684 0.8296 131.5305 0.8881 183.0491 0.9012 1.4192 0.3110 1.9670 0.3369 2.8968 0.3530
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I asked myself if it started with 0 or 1, now I know.