# Pgfplotstable multicolumn table with dec sep align and Tabularx

Tags: pgfplotstable, tabularx, multicolumn

I would like to implement a multicolumn table with Pgfplotstable that aligns on one side the number of the columns by dec sep align and secondly aligns the whole table by Tabularx. A version without Tabularx can be seen below:

[image: Example without Tabularx]

Similar questions have been asked [Dec sep align & \multicolumn incompatibility?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74314/dec-sep-align-multicolumn-incompatibility) and here [Setting table width with pgfplotstable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132539/setting-table-width-with-pgfplotstable). However, the combination of both have never been asked and seems to make troubles by generating error messages (misplaced noalign).

Sample code for the current table can be found below:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma, 
    header=false,
    % column type=,
    % begin table={\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXXXXXXXX}},
    % end table={\end{tabularx}},
    every head row/.style={
        before row={\toprule%
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{Test Case}  & 
            \multicolumn{6}{c}{Extraction Times (ms)} & 
            \multicolumn{6}{c}{Nr. of Nodes} &  
            \multicolumn{6}{c}{Nr. of Edges}\\
        }, after row={\midrule}
    },
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    display columns/0/.style={column name={}, string type, column type={l}},
    display columns/1/.style={column name={Avg.}, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=3, dec sep align={l}},
    display columns/2/.style={column name={Min.}, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=3, dec sep align={l}},
    display columns/3/.style={column name={Max.}, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=3, dec sep align={l}},
    display columns/4/.style={column name={Avg.}, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=3, dec sep align={l}},
    display columns/5/.style={column name={Min.}, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=3, dec sep align={l}},
    display columns/6/.style={column name={Max.}, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=3, dec sep align={l}},
    display columns/7/.style={column name={Avg.}, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=3, dec sep align={l}},
    display columns/8/.style={column name={Min.}, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=3, dec sep align={l}},
    display columns/9/.style={column name={Max.}, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=3, dec sep align={l}},                         
]
{
1,0.9010122055414193,0.026615,63.07629,77.97766468758836,25,237,76.97766468758836,24,236
2,0.8516347167090754,0.015717,98.322158,29.500989539157477,9,86,28.500989539157477,8,85
3,0.8279668317783433,0.012067,46.588329,15.549901046084253,5,44,14.549901046084253,4,43
4,0.8110630712468193,0.010986,46.879446,10.682499293186316,4,30,9.682499293186316,3,29
}
```

I have already changed the number of columns of the tabularx as doc sec align needs two columns without any success.

Any suggestions and solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please complete your MWE with your `documentclass` and page setting? Your table goes behind the borders of an ordinary `article` class.