# How can I use \multicolumn in a \pgfplotstable table?

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, multicolumn

In my experiments with pgfplotstable, I've run into some bumps:

- merging multiple columns
- [adding formatting commands to text within cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236210/how-can-i-use-formatting-commands-in-a-pgfplotstable-table)

## Problem

I cannot seem to properly add a `\multicolumn{}{}{}` to my portable graphics format plot table.

I've viewed the following questions:

- [Multiple Multi columns with pgfplotstable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84907/multiple-multi-columns-with-pgfplotstable)
- [Pgfplotstable multicolumn table with dec sep align and Tabularx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214553/pgfplotstable-multicolumn-table-with-dec-sep-align-and-tabularx)

## Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{multicol}% <-- Don't think this is needed.
\pgfplotstableset{% Global config
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    col sep=&,
    row sep=\\,
    column type=l,
    column type={>{\fontseries{bx}\selectfont\color{orange}}l}, %see sec 2.6 for defining column types
    string type,
    postproc cell content/.append style={ % see sec 3.2
    /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\fontseries{\seriesdefault}\selectfont\color{black}}{}}
}%

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{%
col1 & col2 & col3\\ 
here & more & stuff\\
for & good & looks \\ % \multicolumn{2}{c}{good looks} % <-- Replacing the cells "good" and look" with this causes problems
}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is better to give a *true minmal working example*. There is much stuff, which has nothing to do with the problem...

Maybe, you are looking for something like this:

```
\pgfplotstableset{
every row no 0/.append style={after row={
for & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\color{red} good   looks} \\
}},
}
```

[image]

```
% arara: lualatex

%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

%\usepackage{multicol}% <-- Don't think this is needed.

\pgfplotstableset{% Global config
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    col sep=&,
    row sep=\\,
    column type=l,
    column type={>{\fontseries{bx}\selectfont\color{orange}}l}, %see sec 2.6 for defining column types
    string type,
    postproc cell content/.append style={ % see sec 3.2
    /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\fontseries{\seriesdefault}\selectfont\color{black}}{}
},
%
}%

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableset{
every row no 0/.append style={after row={
for & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\color{red} good   looks} \\
}},
}



\pgfplotstabletypeset{%
col1 & col2 & col3\\ 
here & more & stuff\\
for & good  & looks \\ % \multicolumn{2}{c}{good looks} \\% <-- Replacing the cells "good" and look" with this causes problems
}%
\end{document}
```